# find command return file structure twice?

Tags: find

I tried to list the file structure in a directory to save a snapshot of the structure in the system. I'm trying it with find since it's quick and native to linux.

I tried:

```
find $PWD * -ls
```

But somehow the file structure was returned twice, like this:

```
  8022    1 drwxr-x---   2 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 23:15 /home/user1/projects/wrapper
  8158   10 -rw-r-----   1 user1     my-group      160 Jun 28 23:15 /home/user1/projects/wrapper/wrapper.sh
    41    1 drwxr-x---   3 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 13:17 /home/user1/projects/WGS
    42    1 drwxr-x---   2 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 13:18 /home/user1/projects/WGS/test
    41    1 drwxr-x---   3 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 13:17 WGS
    42    1 drwxr-x---   2 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 13:18 WGS/test
  8022    1 drwxr-x---   2 user1     my-group        3 Jun 28 23:15 wrapper
  8158   10 -rw-r-----   1 user1     my-group      160 Jun 28 23:15 wrapper/wrapper.sh
```

Why is the behavior of find like this? Is there a way to only print it once? Ideally, I prefer to have the full path retained.

If there is a better tool to archive file structures, please feel free to let me know!

Thanks!

Edit:

I understood why I got the result thanks to  Rhymoid and John1024.

I'm wondering does anyone know what are the numbers in the first two column mean?

Comment: `find $PWD * -ls` shell-expands to `find /home/user1/projects` followed by all file names in the current directory (`wrapper WGS`) followed by `-ls`. You're actually asking `find` to do this. Instead, you probably want `find . -ls`.

Comment: Or, to retain the full path, `find "$PWD"  -ls ` (no star)

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks! find $PWD -ls works! you can make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: does anyone know what are the numbers in the first two column mean?

Comment: Please refer to [the manual of GNU `find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (or type `man find` in the shell). It explains that `-ls` lists the "current file in `ls -dils` format on standard output." If you then look at the [manual of `ls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), you'd see that the first number is from `-i` and represents the [inode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4950/what-is-an-inode) of the file, and the second number is from `-s` and represents the number of file system blocks occupied by the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks, @Rhymoid, I got them.. hard to find info on these. How about the 4th column, I understand it's some kind of number for the level of the directory but there is no formal description in ls man page

Comment: That is the number of [hard links](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212304/what-is-the-difference-in-file-size-between-symbolic-and-hard-links) to the inode of the file. Roughly speaking, a file is a hard link to an inode. In certain file systems, directories can only have two (from the parent and as `.`; [the root is its own parent](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5711/why-does-have-an-entry/)) or three (from the parent, as `.`, and as `..`) hard links to them. Any other file *usually* is the only hard link to its inode, but you could use the `ln` utility to create more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is working just fine. It does exactly what you say it should do.

From the output, I infer that `/home/user1/projects` is your current directory, which contains only the files `WGS` and `wrapper` (both directories). When you pass your command

```
find $PWD * -ls
```

in the shell, it is expanded (using a ridiculously complex system; most of it is [standardised as part of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06)) before it is actually executed. In this case,

- the word `find` is expanded to `find`,
- the word `$PWD` is expanded to `/home/user1/projects`; that is the value of the environment variable `PWD` (path of the working directory),
- the word `*` is expanded to `WGS wrapper` due to [pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06);
- the word `-ls` is expanded to `-ls`.

The resulting command is

```
find /home/user1/projects WGS wrapper -ls
```

which indeed prints all files in the current directory and its descendants twice.

---

What you probably want is

```
find . -ls
```

Word expansion doesn't change this command, and `find` interprets `.` as the current working directory. Alternatively, if you want to retain the full path, you want

```
find "$PWD" -ls
```

Word expansion does change this command, but the double quotes around `$PWD` ensure that if the expansion introduces any spaces, it will still remain one argument.